# Is a completely custom keyboard, for my app only, acceptable?

Tags: ios, keyboard, appstore-approval

I'm working on an iOS app that requires a custom keyboard. I'd like some help in knowing if I am allowed to create a custom keyboard for my app only and if I'm allowed to set a custom height on it as well. I've never worked done anything with creating custom keyboards for my app only, and would appreciate if some guidance were to be provided on how to go by starting this if this concept were to be acceptable by Apple. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's review policies and not an appropriate programming question.

Comment: It is an appropriate question because I'm asking for programming guidance on how to begin if it is acceptable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally acceptable inside your app! and there should be no acceptance criteria for that!

You can even make a custom keyboard to use outside your app (I developed two myself), however there are acceptance criteria for that (like having a button to switch to another keyboard).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response, What about if I make a keyboard size with a smaller height than normal for in-app only. Would that still be acceptable?

Comment: Hello, yes you can actually, it is totally acceptable and there are many apps that have that in app! There are also custom keyboards in app on github that can help you so you don't start from scratch. If my answer helped you out please mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, I'm going to start working on it. Thank you so much!